# Jquery expected expression

Tags: jquery

enter code hereI have written following jquery in my code. It says expected expression. And no errors.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
    $('#Submit').click(
        function () {
            if ($('#Message').val() == '') {
                alert('You need to type a Message to send');
                return false;
            } else {
                alert('Your Message sent successfully');
                return false;
            }
            );
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket before the final closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#Submit').click(function () {
    if ($('#Message').val() == '') {
        alert('You need to type a Message to send');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Your Message sent successfully');
        return false;
    }
}); <--- missing this brace (the '}')
```

Format your code and the issue is clear

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `}`:

```
$('#Submit').click(function () {
    if ($('#Message').val() == '') {
        alert('You need to type a Message to send');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Your Message sent successfully');
        return false;
    }
});
^---- This was missing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Submit').click(
    function ()
    {
        if($('#Message').val() == '')
        {
            alert('You need to type a Message to send');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Your Message sent successfully');
            return false;
        }
    }
 );
```